# IntelliJ IDEA maven repository

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a scala project in IntelliJ 13 and I'm trying to add http://repo.spray.io as a repository so I can pull down newer spray snapshots. See http://spray.io/project-info/maven-repository/

The project is made up of about 5 Scala JAR projects,and I tried the pom.xml in the root of one of them to no avail. I am not sure if a pom.xml will be used in a Scala jar project, but it seemed to be ignored.

I also tried ~/.m2/settings.xml (which doesn't exist on my machine), but either I was not able to compose it correctly, or it was ignored as well.

The intellij approach is confusing. If I add the repository and click "test" it comes up with "no repositories found".  I don't really know what it's trying to do.

How can I add this repository, preferably globally, not per project? I do not use sbt.